# Find piece of phrase in idexes

Tags: elasticsearch

With ElasticSearch, is there a way to find piece of phrase in my indexes.

Example:

with text

> The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or
> language problems.
>
> Avoid asking opinion-based questions.

Elastic JSON example

```
{
"_index": "index_test",
"_type": "textes",
"_id": "28479",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "title": "The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."
  }
}
```

If I search "help". I Want to find the document AND return "is here to help you with".

Comment: Coud you give a sample of data (json format) from elasticsearch?

Comment: Thanks for the example, on more precision, when you say  return "is here to help you with", you don't want the full text? Just a part of them, which one if yes?

Comment: The part that hit the query + few words before and few words after